# Expand Join to not limit data

Tags: sql, join

I have a weird question - I understand that Joins return matching data based on the 'ON' stipulation, however the problem I am facing is I need the Business date back for both tables but at the same time i need to join on the date in order to get the totals correct

See below code:

```
Select 
o.Resort,
o.Business_Date,
Occupied,
Comps,
House,
ADR,
Room_Revenue,
Occupied-(Comps+House) AS DandT,
Coalesce(gd.Projected_Occ1,0) AS Projected_Occ1,
Occupied-(Comps+House)+Coalesce(gd.Projected_Occ1,0) as Total
from Occupancy o
left join Group_Details_HF gd
on o.Business_Date = gd.Business_Date
and o.Resort = gd.resort
UNION ALL
select 
o.Resort,
o.Business_Date,
Occupied,
Comps,
House,
ADR,
Room_Revenue,
Occupied-(Comps+House) AS DandT,
Coalesce(gd.Projected_Occ1,0) AS Projected_Occ1,
Coalesce(Occupied-(Comps+House),0)+Coalesce(gd.Projected_Occ1,0) as Total
from Occupancy_Forecast o
FULL OUTER JOIN Group_Details_HF gd
on o.Business_Date = gd.Business_Date
and o.Resort = gd.resort
```

Currently, this gives me the desired results from the Occupancy and Occupancy forecast table however when the business date does not exist in the occupancy forecast table it ignores the group_details table, I need the results to combine the dates when they exist in both or give the unique results for each when there is no match

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to create another pivot table storing the  details from Group_Details_HF and then Union together the two tables which has given me the desired result rather than fiddling with the join :)